# cmake find_package(OpenGL REQUIRED) failed without any error message

Tags: c++, opengl, cmake

I'm trying to use cmake (Windows10 + VS2010) to find OpenGL and I used the following code:

```
find_package(OpenGL REQUIRED)
message(STATUS "OpenGL_FOUND:= ${OpenGL_FOUND}")

if(OpenGL_FOUND)
    message('OpenGL_FOUND-is-true')
else(OpenGL_FOUND)
    message('OpenGL_FOUND-is-false')
endif(OpenGL_FOUND)

message(STATUS "OPENGL_INCLUDE_DIR:= ${OPENGL_INCLUDE_DIR}")
message(STATUS "OPENGL_LIBRARY:= ${OPENGL_LIBRARY}")
message(STATUS "OPENGL_LIBRARIES:= ${OPENGL_LIBRARIES}")
```

The output is:

```
OpenGL_FOUND:= 
'OpenGL_FOUND-is-false'
OPENGL_INCLUDE_DIR:= 
OPENGL_LIBRARY:= glu32;opengl32
OPENGL_LIBRARIES:= glu32;opengl32
```

the arg `REQUIRED` in find_package does NOT take effect, why is that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking in the [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindOpenGL.html), as unexpected, the variable is not `OpenGL_FOUND`, but `OPENGL_FOUND`. I guess you will have something more consistent with the following:

```
find_package(OpenGL REQUIRED)
message(STATUS "OPENGL_FOUND:= ${OPENGL_FOUND}")

if(OPENGL_FOUND)
    message('OPENGL_FOUND-is-true')
else()
    message('OPENGL_FOUND-is-false')
endif()

message(STATUS "OPENGL_INCLUDE_DIR:= ${OPENGL_INCLUDE_DIR}")
message(STATUS "OPENGL_LIBRARY:= ${OPENGL_LIBRARY}")
message(STATUS "OPENGL_LIBRARIES:= ${OPENGL_LIBRARIES}")

add_executable(foo main.cpp)
target_include_directories(foo PUBLIC ${OPENGL_INCLUDE_DIR})
target_link_libraries(foo ${OPENGL_LIBRARIES})
```

Looking in the [source code](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/master/Modules/FindOpenGL.cmake), `OPENGL_INCLUDE_DIR` is not set on Windows, except for cygwin, and should indeed be empty in your case.

Note that repeating the condition is optional in `else()` and `endif()`.

Comment: so what's the correct way to include opengl on Windows? copy the opengl library to the IDE default include dir(e.g., the *inherited values* `$(WindowsSdkDir)include`)?

Comment: The headers should already be in the default include dir. Just do the "normal" calls. I edited my answer

Answer (score 0):

The real answer is this part of the https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_package.html:

> In Module mode the loaded find module is responsible to honor the request detailed by these variables; see the find module for details.

So you could argue that this is a bug in the FindOpenGL.cmake module. Alternatively, the requirement by `find_package` that each and every module is supposed to handle the same thing can also be considered a bug. Or that they don't have any process in place to only ship modules that satisfy these requirements.